# how to set the axis limits in a subfigure in matplolib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I would like to insert a small plot in another plot. The data in the
insert is very different from the main plot, the scales are unrelated.

The main plot works fine, the insert is the problem. I cannot set the
axis values of the insert. Can someone help me setting the drawing
range (axis) for the subplot?

This is the smallest program that shows the problem. The insert is
empty, it is always showing the area `[0,1,0,1]` .

matplotlib version 1.4.2

Code -

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

def init_plot():
    global ax, sub_axes
    fig = plt.figure(2)  # create an instance to create subplots in
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    sub_axes = plt.axes([.0, .0, .25, .25], axisbg='y')
    plt.setp(sub_axes, xticks=[], yticks=[])

def draw_blobs():
    blob=[[0.0, 0.0], [1.5, 0.0], [0.75, 0.75]]
    blob2=[[5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 5.0], [5.5, 5.5]]
    ax.add_patch(Polygon(blob, closed=True, color='0.5'))
    sub_axes.add_patch(Polygon(blob2, closed=True, color='0.5'))

init_plot()
draw_blobs()
ax.axis([0, 2, 0, 2])
#sub_axis.axis([5, 6, 5, 6])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `xlim` and `ylim` of sub_axes

```
sub_axes.set_xlim(5, 6)
sub_axes.set_ylim(5, 6)
```